# Network Up Script does not work properly

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

i wrote a Script called "drok", put it in /etc/network/if-up.d/,made it executable and changes ownership to 755. 
When i connect to wifi this script should be execute as a whole.
Unfortunately only the first line of code gets executed.
So i copied "drok" as drok.sh in my userspace and used the line to execute drok.sh. 
Yet only the first line of code gets executed. 
If i execute drok.sh manually everythings works well. 
Do you have any idee how to fix that?

Comment: Can you post the contents of that script?

Comment: #!/bin/zsh

kill $(ps aux | grep '[d]ropbox' | awk '{print $2}') &> /dev/null 
dropbox start &> /dev/null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue relates to the user you're running as. Try running `sudo ./drok.sh` and see if it works to confirm this. (You may want to temporarily remove your `&>/dev/null`s to see why it's failing). If this is indeed the problem, I can think of two possible reasons:

1. `dropbox` may not be in the path for root. In this case, fully qualify the path to it.
2. `dropbox` may be expecting to run as you and not as root. In this case, try doing `su - YOUR_USERNAME -c 'dropbox start'` instead of `dropbox start`.